# Impala The Cloudera Manager Agent got an unexpected response from this role's web server

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

i have done an hadoop cluster installation with cloudera manager. After this installation impala status has become bad. 
I have the following error for master node:

```
Web Server Status
```

and this one for nodes with imapala daemon:

```
Impala Daemon Ready Check, Web Server Status
```

looking into logs i have found some errors:

```
The health test result for IMPALAD_WEB_METRIC_COLLECTION has become bad: The Cloudera Manager Agent got an unexpected response from this role's web server.
```

looking into cloudera-scm-agent.log there are those errors:

```
1261 Monitor-HostMonitor throttling_logger ERROR    (29 skipped) Failed to collect NTP metrics
```

i tryed to install NTP (sudo apt-get install ntp) but after this installation HDFS, HIVE, YARN and others services goes bad, removing that only impala goes bad.

```
MainThread agent        ERROR    Failed to connect to previous supervisor.
```

Another error is this:

```
Monitor-GenericMonitor throttling_logger ERROR    Error fetching metrics at 'http://nodo-1:50075/jmx'
```

i tried looking all hostnames and seems correct...
so, what is this problem? how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I also had problem with NTP, the problem still existed after installing NTP , but when I done **sudo service ntp restart** the error was fixed